# Ativar um evento quando ele esta em movimento

Tags: android

Tenho uma `ImageView` em movimento na tela, eu preciso executar uma animação quando ela for tocada pelo usuário, porém `image.setOnClickListener` e também `image.onTouchListener` não estão sendo ativados quando a imagem é clicada.

res/anim/translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
```

activity que contem  o start da animação

```
private void IniciarAnimacoes() {

    //Animaçoes dos pinguins
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.movimento_pinguim);
    anim.reset();

    imgPiguim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPinguim);
    imgPiguim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_pinguim_anima);
    animaPiguim = (AnimationDrawable)imgPiguim.getBackground();
    imgPiguim.clearAnimation();
    imgPiguim.startAnimation(anim);
```

No codigo o pinguim fica pulando na tela, eu preciso que quando o usuario o toquem em algum momento acione um evento.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso, com algum exemplo ou quais outros parâmetros devem ser utilizados?

Answer (score 0):

No método `onCreate()` obtenha uma referência à *ImageView* e atribua-lhe um *onClickListener*:

```
    imgPiguim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPinguim);

    imgPiguim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Código a ser executado quando a imagem for clicada
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

No método `onClick()` coloque o código que deve ser executado quando a imagem for clicada.

Altere o método `IniciarAnimacoes()` para usar o objecto *imgPiguim* obtido no `onCreate()`

```
private void IniciarAnimacoes() {

    //Animaçoes dos pinguins
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.movimento_pinguim);
    anim.reset();

    //Isto deveria ser passado para o `onCreate()`
    imgPiguim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_pinguim_anima);

    //Comentei por que não é utilizada
    //animaPiguim = (AnimationDrawable)imgPiguim.getBackground();

    imgPiguim.clearAnimation();
    imgPiguim.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: pois entao é exatamente assim que estou fazendo, eo evento nao responde na imagem que esta em movimento

Comment: Você já dizia isso na pergunta por isso, antes de responder, eu testei o código e ele funciona.